# OData unbound function return type references entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I would like to implement geosearch functionality for different entities. I have a generic result class, which contains the distance from the given coordinates, and a reference to the entity.

```
public class GeoSearchResult<T> : IGeoSearchResult where T : class
{
    public T Row { get; set; }
    public double? Distance { get; set; }
}
```

I configured the function with the following code:

```
var function = builder.Function("FooGeoSearch");
        function.Parameter<double>("lon");
        function.Parameter<double>("lat");
        function.Parameter<double>("radiusInMiles");
        function.ReturnsCollection<GeoSearchResult<Foo>>();
```

It throws the following exception when I try to run it:
The complex type '.GeoSearchResult`1Foo' refers to the entity type 'Foo' through the property 'Row'.

Is there a workaround?